# ASP MVC 5 Running HTML5 Client and Web API server on different domains

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-web-api

I was planning to split my ASP.NET MVC5 project into 2 projects.

Part-1: WEB API server that will do the Business Logic Data access via EF6 etc.

Part-2 ASP.NET MVC 5 Client with Razor Views & JQuery Ajax calls to server (not a pure Single Page App - SPA)

2 parts running on separate IIS servers.
SQL server is not (may not be) accessible directly from client

I can get the credentials from client side and pass it to web api server to authenticate the user and get a Token to access the server api.

Question is: Is it possible to do Authentication & Authorization on client side with that server Token.

Since there is no local database of Users on client side therefore no user roles or membership stuff.

How can I authorize some Client side MVC razor Views or controllers based on server side credentials.

Will I have to implement a custom membership Provider on Client side that pulls user roles etc from server via an api?

I know there will be Cross-domain issues to resolve.

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the SQL Server instance should never be directly accessible to the client, that's the whole point of the web api/service.

As far as authentication with the web service, you will need to work with an access token. As your building a new MVC 5 web api project, if you choose Individual User Account Authentication, VS will build in a lot of the account information for you. You can then use attributes like  to control which controllers and actions require authentication. You can even get more granular and define what roles can access certain controllers or actions. On the client side it might look something like this:

```
var login = function () {
   var url = "/Token";
   var data = $('formData').serialize();
   data = data + "&grant_type=password";
   $.post(url, data)
     .success(saveAccessToken);  //once the token is saved, it will need to appended to every request

   return false();
}

$('#login').click(login);
```

If you are thinking about authentication from the server side inside a controller, use the [WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to interact with the web service, similar to the way the client side script above does.

Finally, for the cross-domain issues. There is a [Nuget Package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors/) that you should check out. This package will take care of most of the configurations needed for the server side code to accept the requests. For a little background on CORS, check out [this site](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api). Hope that helps!